# Is normalization in 3NF applicable on a schema consisting of multiple candidate keys?

Tags: rdbms, database-normalization, 3nf

I have a relation consisting of the following attributes:

**`Employee:`**
`Emp_Id(Primary Key), Name, E_mail, Phone_Number, Date_Of_Joining, Address`

I'm assuming that two people can have the same `Name` or `Address`, **but** not the same `E_mail` Id's or `Phone_Number`'s(*i.e. they should be unique*).

So, according to what I know to normalize the table; I need to separate `E-mail` and `Phone_Number` information into a separate table (for 3NF):

From [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form):

> The third normal form (3NF) is a normal form used in database
>   normalization. 3NF was originally defined by E.F. Codd in 1971.[2]
>   Codd's definition states that a table is in 3NF if and only if both of
>   the following conditions hold:
>
> - The relation R (table) is in second normal form (2NF)
> - Every non-prime
>     attribute of R is non-transitively dependent on every key of R.

So I divide the main table into these resulting tables:

**`E_Mail Information`:** `E_Mail_Id(Primary Key), E_Mail Address, ...`

**`Contact/Phone Number Information`:** `Phone_Id(Primary Key), Phone_Number, ...`

(New)**`Employee:`**
`Emp_Id(Primary Key), Name, E_mail_Id(foreign key), Phone_Number_Id(foreign key), Date_Of_Joining, Address`

My question(s) are

1. Without dividing the relation as given above in order to achieve 3NF, could we have just let **`Employee`** be as it is without running into trouble (***this question is only specific to the example I described above***)?
2. Even after dividing the table we might have values which despite being Foreign keys are unique(due to one-to-one relation) and therefore be considered as candidate keys in (New)`Employee` relation which are `E_mail_Id` and `Phone_Number_Id`. So wouldn't they violate 3NF?

Comment: Although it doesn't affect the validity of your question, the assumption that phone numbers are not shared is a dubious proposition in the real world.  Landlines are frequently shared in houses — not everyone has only a mobile number.  And I know of communal email addresses too (in some sections of my extended family).

Comment: Yes definitely. I'm just taking assumptions to understand a concept without bothering about its practicality which is the sole reason behind the first question I asked.

Comment: Hi. The definition of 3NF refers to FDs & CKs & other things. The FDs determine CKs & other things. So where are your FDs? Find a textbook & find a 3NF algorithm & follow it & ask a question where stuck. Your question asks us to write a textbook chapter & a bespoke tutorial.

Comment: Normalization never requires creating new attributes. You created Emain_id and Phone_number_id. Might be worth thinking hard about who taught you to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Restating your assumptions

*This is not intended to change your assumptions but merely to clarify them.*

You have a relation schema:

**`Employee`**: `Emp_Id`, `Name`, `E_mail`, `Phone_Number`, `Date_Of_Joining`, `Address`

and you are stipulating for the purposes of this question that:

1. Each employee has one email address and that is unique to them.
2. Each employee has one phone number and that is unique to them.

Thus, you have three 'prime attributes' (in Codd's notation) or three Candidate Keys for this schema:

1. `Emp_Id`
2. `E_mail`
3. `Phone_number`

Given an employee ID, the employee is uniquely determined; given the phone number, the employee is uniquely determined; given the email address, the employee is uniquely determined.

#### Your relation schema is in 3NF

If what's stated above is a correct interpretation of the relation schema, then your observation about "I need to separate E-mail and Phone_Number information into a separate table (for 3NF)" is wrong.  There is no need to separate them.

Under the stated conditions, your relation schema is already in 3NF; indeed, it is in BCNF (Boyce-Codd Normal Form) too.  The relation is in 2NF and there are no transitive dependencies.

**Answer to Question 1**

Yes — you could leave the table as it is because it is already in 3NF.

**Answer to Question 2**

No — because 3NF does not require a single candidate key, which you seem to think is necessary.  Also, there's no particular requirement to store the Email ID in the main table; the Email address table would have a primary key which is the Employee ID, and doesn't need an Email ID number because email addresses are unique to the employee (under the rules of engagement for this question).  Similarly for phone numbers.

---

In practice, an employee might have multiple email addresses, and may have multiple phone numbers, even just for their private use (separately from a corporate email address and corporate phone number).  Under those circumstances, you'd have a 'non-empty list of email addresses' and a 'non-empty list of phone numbers' for a particular employee, and then you would need separate tables to record them. The Phone Number would be the primary key of the Phone Information table, and the Employee ID would be an FK in the phone number table; the Email Address would be the primary key of the Email table and the Employee ID would be an FK in the email address table.

Your relation schema would have to list these multiple entries somehow, and that wouldn't be 1NF, let alone 2NF or 3NF (under some reasonable assumptions for how the lists might be represented).  And the 'non-empty' criterion would need careful enforcement.

Comment: Okay! Actually I thought the transitive dependency `Emp_Id -> Email_Id -> Emp_Name` would violate `3NF`. So we shouldn't be looking out for `X -> Y -> Z` if `Y` happens to be a candidate key as well, right?

Comment: That isn’t a transitive dependency.

Comment: An example of a transitive dependency would be in a broken down US (snail mail) address with zip code and state.  The zip code determines the state, so if both columns were in a table, there would theoretically be a transitive dependency.  But I see no such dependency here.

Comment: Right.  "A transitive dependency is a functional dependency in which X → Z (X determines Z) indirectly, by virtue of X → Y and Y → Z (where it is not the case that Y → X)." [Transitive Dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form#cite_note-4) Shame how I missed the part in the brackets. :(

Comment: @Bateman Read the definition. What matters is transitive FDs of non-prime attributes on CKs.